# Как создать нужный json ответ

Tags: python, json

Я новичек в программировании, пытаюсь создать json ответ. Есть ответ от WMI - принтера системные, есть название и порт. Принтеров несколько. Пока получается только собрать ответ в виде -

- Принтер1:

  - Название1: Порт1
- Принтер2:

  - Название2: Порт2
  - ....... и так далее

Хочу получить ответ в виде:

- Принтера:

  - Название1: Порт1
  - Название2: Порт2

  ---

Помогите решить сию задачку

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться тем, кто захочет помочь :)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать ответ в формате JSON, вам нужно собрать данные в словаре Python, а затем использовать функцию json.dumps для преобразования этого словаря в формат JSON.

```
import json

data = {'Принтеры': [{'Название1': 'Порт1'}, {'Название2': 'Порт2'}, ...]}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

В этом примере data - это словарь, который содержит ключ 'Принтеры', значением которого является список словарей с информацией о каждом принтере. Функция json.dumps преобразует этот словарь в формат JSON.